# print trees in preorder separated by commas

Tags: c++, tree, preorder

I have following function to print trees in in order that works properly:

```
void PrintInOrder(TTreeNode const * const pRoot) {
    if (pRoot != 0) {
        PrintInOrder(pRoot->pLeft);
        if(pRoot->pLeft) std::cout << ",";
        std::cout << pRoot->Data;
        if(pRoot->pRight) std::cout << ",";
        PrintInOrder(pRoot->pRight);
    }
}
```

This is my preorder printing function:

```
void PrintPreOrder(TTreeNode const * const pRoot)  {
    if (pRoot != 0) {
        std::cout << pRoot->Data << std::endl;
        PrintPreOrder(pRoot->pLeft);
        PrintPreOrder(pRoot->pRight);
    }
}
```

As i'm too stupid to figure it out how to print it separated the way like the inorder function i hope you guys can help me out!

thanks!

Update:

Preorder function works now, so is this the right postorder function?

```
void PrintPostOrder(TTreeNode const * const pRoot)  {
        if (pRoot != 0) {
            PrintPostOrder(pRoot->pLeft);
            if(pRoot->pLeft) std::cout << ",";
            PrintPostOrder(pRoot->pRight);
            if(pRoot->pRight) std::cout << ",";
            std::cout << pRoot->Data;
        }
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] before very long.  You've got 90% or more of the answer in the `PrintInOrder()` function.  Adapting that to the `PrintPreOrder()` and `PrintPostOder()` functions is a trivial exercise in editing.

Answer (score 1):

```
void PrintPreOrder(TTreeNode const * const pRoot)  {
    if (pRoot != 0) {
        std::cout << pRoot->Data << std::endl;
        if(pRoot->pLeft || pRoot->pRight) std::cout << ",";
        PrintPreOrder(pRoot->pLeft);
        if(pRoot->pLeft && pRoot->pRight) std::cout << ",";
        PrintPreOrder(pRoot->pRight);
    }
}
```

Also please note this will print the tree in preorder traversal.

Comment: thx for your help, mixed preorder and postorder in my question.

Answer (score 1):

This is the proper way to do it:

```
void PrintPreOrder(TTreeNode const * const pRoot)  {
    if (pRoot != 0) {
        std::cout << pRoot->Data << std::endl;
        // take care of left node
        if(pRoot->pLeft || pRoot->pRight) std::cout << ",";
        PrintPreOrder(pRoot->pLeft);
        // take care of right node
        if(pRoot->pLeft && pRoot->pRight) std::cout << ",";
        PrintPreOrder(pRoot->pRight);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **in-order** version:

1. Visits the left subtree.
2. Prints the root's data.
3. Visits the right subtree.

What you want to do in **pre-order** version is:

1. Print the root's data.
2. Visit the left subtree.
3. Visit the right subtree.

so it should look like this:

```
void PrintPreOrder(TTreeNode const * const pRoot) {
    if (pRoot) {

        // print the root:
        std::cout << pRoot->Data;
        
        // visit the left subtree:
        if (pRoot->pLeft) {
            std::cout << ",";
            PrintPreOrder(pRoot->pLeft);
        }
        
        // visit the right subtree:
        if (pRoot->pRight) {
            std::cout << ",";
            PrintPreOrder(pRoot->pRight);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so i don't really need the OR and AND conditions that was posted bfore i think?

Comment: @schreda: That's just another way of expressing the same logic. If there is left OR right, then 1 comma will be printed, if there are both, 2 commas will be printed. The result of my code is the same :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is years old, but still helpful!

I was wondering how to do this myself, and found this question, but realize there is an easy answer:

```
void Preorder(Node* root){
  if(root==NULL){
    return;
  }
  cout << root->data << " ";
  Preorder(root->left);
  Preorder(root->right);
}
```

You're starting with the root of the tree. If the root is `null`, the code is done.

Otherwise, print out the data at that node.

Then, we call `Preorder` on the `left` and `right` subtree for that node, which is now the `root` of its own subtree. It is important we call the left subtree first, as this is preorder (right subtree for post order).

We check if the `root` is `null`, so we don't have to worry if the left subtree is `null` or the `right` subtree is `null` individually. If the node is `null`, just backtrack.